# PHP - Mysql - Security

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have written following PHP and Javascript code to prompt a user to delete a record, which works great.

I somehow do not think that this code is secure, the reason is if you run the script in a browser, and do a View-source a person will be able to see that I am using `delete.php` and passing an ID to delete the record.So there can be a possibility of deleting the records using `delete.php`

Is there a way to secure the code.

**My PHP code is**

```
<?
        $rs = "SELECT * FROM my tablename";

                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$rs);           
                    $data = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                    $responses = array();
                    if($data != 0) {

                          while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                          {
                          $res_id=$results['id'];
                            echo "<tr id='".$results['id']."'><td>".$results['_name'] ."</td>";         

                            echo "<td><a alt='delete'  href='javascript:;' onclick='fun_delete(".$results['id'].")' title='delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span> ";
                            e
                          }
                    } 

        ?>
```

**My Javascript code is**

```
<script>
function fun_delete(x)
 {

 //alert(x);
  var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the record?");
  if (result) {
    //alert(x);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {id:x},
            success: function(data){

                if(data){

                   location.reload(); 
                }
            },
            error:function(){
                // JQ.fancybox.hideLoading();
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
}
}

 </script>
```

Comment: On the server side (php) you should verify that the user has permission to delete the record. If you respond with anything else than http status 200 (ok) then your jquery code will enter the error callback instead of success. You can use that to display an error message (record doesnt exist, you dont have permission to delete this record, etc)

Comment: @JimL By user do you mean the SQL User? Error Callback from PHP code?

Comment: No the current user / the user sending the request.

Comment: Even when you don't view source - by observing Network traffic in Chrome you can easily see what's going on - what kind of URLs is the data sent to. Does it matter? Security shouldn't rely on obscurity of your code - as long as you: 1) validate the data (what will happen if user sends different data than id) 2) implement ACL for the user (should user be allowed to delete given record) then you're fine.